# Preventing SQL injections in php

Tags: php

What is the best way to check if the user entered malicious code in a form field? I have looked at other questions, but those are just checking if what was entered and if it was what they wanted (phone num. in phone field). I'm looking for protection from SQL injections.

Comment: clean the input when it's processed, strip tags, use PDO etc.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have to determine the issue exactly and regard what do you have tried to do. You could able to [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help.

Comment: I did say that I needed something to prevent MySQL injections. Could you point out where I can be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are meant for preventing SQL injection and they are enough when we are talking about SQL injection. But, there are some other attacks you should also prevent. [XSS](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cross-Site-Scripting-(XSS).html), [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard) and others.

**SQL injection:**

Prepared statements basically work like this:

1. Prepare: An SQL statement template is created and sent to the database. Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters (labeled "?"). Example: INSERT INTO MyGuests VALUES(?, ?, ?)
2. The database parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on the SQL statement template, and stores the result without executing it
3. Execute: At a later time, the application binds the values to the parameters, and the database executes the statement. The application may execute the statement as many times as it wants with different values

Sample:

```
// Prepare the statement.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

// Bind parameters.
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// Set parameters.
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";

// Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Close the statement.
$stmt->close();

// Close the connection.
$conn->close();
```

Source: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: So I would want to use this anywhere I accept user input?

Comment: Yes, whenever you are inserting user's input into your database.

Comment: Okay. Should I also use this on login, because I was googling some and I saw that a user could do something like this in the username field. `john' or 1=1; --`

Comment: That's exactly what we fixed right now. That's called **SQL injection** and it's fixed with **prepared statements**.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. Never used MySQL much for storing user input so this is mostly new to me.

Comment: I correct myself: `Whenever you are passing user's input to your database (while sending parameters in SELECT or while UPDATEing or while INSERTing...)`.

Answer (score 0):

use `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` to escape html special characters to html entities if you intend to store or output a user input string. This will help avoid html injection.

Spectarion's answer is a good solution for SQL injection.